# keyeventf_keyup not releasing key

Tags: c#, input, keyboard, mouse

I'm trying to make a C# console based application, that will press and release the space key when I hold down the middle mouse button.

The app works in text based apps (notepad, web browser, etc), seeing how you can just hold down space bar and it'll actually create spaces, but not in games.

For example, if I hold down the middle button, it seems like it doesn't register the keyup event, which means that I have to physically press the space bar to "jump" again.

Here's the code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press down the middle mouse button to jump.\n"
            + "Press F5 to pause the application.");


        while (true)
        {
            if ((GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MIDDLEBUTTON) & KEY_PRESSED) > 0)
            {
                SendInputWithAPI();
            }

            else if ((GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F5) & KEY_PRESSED) > 0)
            {
                PauseFunc();
            }

            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }

    static void SendInputWithAPI()
    {
        INPUT[] Inputs = new INPUT[1];
        INPUT Input = new INPUT();

        Input.type = 1; // 1 = Keyboard Input
        Input.U.ki.wScan = ScanCodeShort.SPACE;
        Input.U.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.SCANCODE;
        Inputs[0] = Input;

        SendInput(1, Inputs, INPUT.Size);

        Random time = new Random();
        int randTime = time.Next(1, 4);

        Thread.Sleep(randTime);

        Input.U.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.KEYUP;
        SendInput(1, Inputs, INPUT.Size);

    }

    static void PauseFunc()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Paused... Press any key to continue.");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

And here's the whole code with all of the structs:

https://hastebin.com/oregahesoh.cs

Did I do the keyup event wrong?

I know for a fact that Thread.Sleep(randTime) isn't a problem, as I've tried different times (up to a second).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it..

This is what I added:

```
        Input.type = 1;
        Input.U.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.KEYUP | KEYEVENTF.SCANCODE;
        Inputs[0] = Input;
```

To the keyup event.